# O que fazer quando um usuário solicita contato via e-mail?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Um exemplo prático: [Menus do Eclipse sumiram](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3882/menus-do-eclipse-sumiram/3884#comment4775_3884)

Qual deve ser a ação?

Pedir ajuda externamente pode ser considerado normal? Há exceções?

Se a situação for um pouco diferente, se estiver pedindo contato direto via e-mail, a ação deve ser a mesma?

Expor o próprio e-mail em mensagens é algo desejável?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O FAQ do SO tem uma pergunta entitulada `How do I contact other users` ("como entro em contato com outros usuários"), que aponta para esta pergunta:

[How do I contact other users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users)

Observe a resposta marcada como correta. Eu menciono seu cerne, verbatim:

> Instant messaging or private messaging is not available: requests to implement that [have been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) to keep focus on questions and answers, and to keep those visible to everyone.

Em português (tradução contextual):

Mensagens privadas ou instantâneas não foram implementadas. Pedidos para fazê-lo [foram sempre negados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) para manter o foco em perguntas e respostas, e mantê-las visiveis para todos.

Se alguém coloca formas de contato em um post, a mesma resposta que cito diz:

> (...)even comments should be relevant to the post, and can be flagged as noise if they are not.

Ou seja: mesmo os comentários devem ser relevantes ao post, e podem ser marcados como ruído se não forem.

Sou contra comunicações externas ao site pois fazem com que o processo de troca de informações em busca de uma resposta ocorra em parte fora do SO/SOePT. Isso vai contra a ideia central do site, que é ser um repositório de problemas comuns e suas soluções onde toda a informação relevante está disponível para qualquer pessoa.

Answer (score 9):

Acho que foge um pouco do princípio do site, pois a ideia é criar um grande repositório de perguntas e respostas em que qualquer pessoa com àquela dúvida possa rapidamente saná-la.

Se esse usuário não consegue ver a imagem outros também podem estar com dificuldades de vê-la. E se essa for a resposta correta os futuros usuários que visitarem a pergunta podem também não conseguir enxergar a resposta.

Pode se tratar de um bug na hora de exibir a imagem, eu não sei, mas eu não concordo com respostas em privado pois não contribuem com a comunidade.