# Informações confidenciais disponibilizadas publicamente

Tags: debate

Quando eu pensei que já tinha visto de tudo nesse mundo eis que me aparece umas dessas na primeira sexta-feira do ano.

Gostaria de, em primeiro lugar, dar os cumprimentos de um Feliz Ano Novo para toda a comunidade e dizer que me sinto feliz em fazer parte dessa comunidade que cresce cada dia mais e ajuda milhares de pessoas que trabalham com TI e as que não trabalham diretamente mas que curtem também.

Hoje tentei ajudar @Henrique Felix que, creio eu, seja um usuário/desenvolver iniciante e percebi que na sua pergunta tinha um link apontando para o dropbox com os códigos fontes do seu projeto, e em um desses códigos fontes estavam informações de acesso a conta de dados com host do provedor, nome de usuário e senha de acesso.

O aconselhei a trocar imediatamente a senha e não mais disponibilizar esse tipo de informação publicamente, o mais duro e saber que esse tipo de desconhecimento ainda ocorre hoje em dia e gostaria de debater com toda a comunidade sobre quais medidas devemos tomar para auxiliar as pessoas a não cometerem esse tipo de erro? Antes de publicar um link avaliar o conteúdo talvez? Gostaria de ouvir a opinião dos nobres colegas.

link da pergunta:

[Pegar valor de 2 select , e exibir os dados de cada um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45601/pegar-valor-de-2-select-e-exibir-os-dados-de-cada-um/45659#45659)

Comment: Questão muito bem levantada.

Comment: aconteceu o mesmo comigo esse dias, deixei um comentário falando disso, porém ainda ficou no histórico de alterações a senha, vou sinalizá-la para remoção!

Comment: Já tivemos este tipo de ocorrência aqui, e a "chefia" providenciou a remoção do histórico também. Na ocasião a pessoa postou as credenciais em base64, mas estava bem evidente o que era.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Um primeiro passo seria editar o conteúdo para remover essas informações.

Não é preciso pedir ao autor, qualquer um com a pontuação necessária pode fazê-lo, ainda que a mesma vá para a fila de aprovação.

Porém isso não basta, ainda será possível ver o histórico de edições.

É importante sinalizar a postagem para os moderadores, quando ocorre esse tipo de vazamento de informações, pois podemos solicitar a exclusão do histórico de edição aos desenvolvedores do Stack Overflow. Neste caso isso só não se aplica porque o usuário conseguiu remover o conteúdo do link. Entretanto algumas vezes informações sigilosas são publicadas diretamente na pergunta.

Por questões de segurança, é bom que o usuário altere as senhas, pois mesmo que o conteúdo fique disponível por pouco tempo, ainda assim há chance das informações vazarem.

Comment: Vale notar que ainda existiriam copias em cache em serviços como webarchive ou no próprio cache do google. Sempre necessário mudar senhas (espero que tenha sido feito) e invalidar links (como foi feito), mesmo depois de remover tudo do histórico aqui.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Cache do google atualiza rapidamente quando o site é movimentado, WebArchive se eu não me engano faz cache por dia e não hora (me corrija se estiver enganado), como utluiz disse, você mesmo pode editar e aguardar. De resto basta recomendar ao usuário que altere a senha do servidor, assim mesmo que qualquer histórico fique, os dados de nada servirão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você pode forçar um snapshot no webarchive a qq momento. Claro que é absurdamente improvável, mas pode ocorrer da "virada" da atualização do _Web Archive_ coincidir com a publicação também. PS: o WA tem periodos bem maiores que um dia entre as visitas, normalmente.

Comment: @Bacco Sim entendo, este é um motivo a mais pelo qual o melhor (na minha opnião) é sugerir ao OP que altere esses dados, por exemplo for login e senha do ftp, que ao menos ele atualize a senha, pois a responsabilidade é dele e não nossa.

Answer (score 6):

O ideal é solicitar ao autor da pergunta que edite a pergunta e remova/substitua o conteúdo sensível que pode ser um usuário e senha, email etc. Caso você veja que ele está demorando(20 minutos?) faça a edição e coloque no campos motivo/descrição que esse tipo de informação não deve ser adicionada na pergunta. Caso seja um comentário sinalize-o.

<sub>Se não me engano tinha uma pergunta sobre esse assunto mas não consegui achar, a mais próxima foi : [O que fazer quando um usuário solicita contato via e-mail?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/733/91)</sub>