# É permitido passar contato pessoal em uma resposta?

Tags: debate, respostas

Hoje, ao passar pela fila de análise, me deparei com uma resposta inusitada, em que o respondente passava o número do seu celular, falando que, qualquer dúvida, a pessoa que perguntou poderia entrar em contato.

Fiquei na dúvida se tirava isso da resposta ou não.

Qual o melhor procedimento para casos assim?

Comment: Acho que segue a mesma linha [Sugerir videoconferência por algum programa pra ajudar em dúvida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5697/sugerir-videoconfer%C3%AAncia-por-algum-programa-pra-ajudar-em-d%C3%BAvida)

Comment: Poderia citar a resposta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Sugerir videoconferência por algum programa pra ajudar em dúvida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5697/sugerir-videoconfer%c3%aancia-por-algum-programa-pra-ajudar-em-d%c3%bavida)

Comment: A resposta foi essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229568/2892, mas já foi editada por outro usuário.

Comment: Já pensou se a pergunta faz sucesso no Google e um monte de gente começa a pedir ajuda pro cara por whatsapp? Nesse caso capaz que o cara edite e tire o celular. Mas em última instância é uma opção pessoal expor esse tipo de informação.

Comment: Li a pergunta citada como possível duplicata: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5697/sugerir-videoconfer%C3%AAncia-por-algum-programa-pra-ajudar-em-d%C3%BAvida, mas achei inconclusiva.

Comment: De qualquer forma, vi que a resposta final ficou sem o celular do cara, então seria ok se eu retirasse. Na minha opinião pessoal, não deveria ser permitido passar contato, já que a resposta deve ser pública para que qualquer um possa consultar depois. Além disso, corre-se o risco do SOpt virar uma plataforma para mero marketing pessoal.

Comment: @MarcellAlves a questão é, a comunidade não faz vista grossa para casos assim, fica a mercê de quem quiser expor contato pessoal, a comunidade não se responsabiliza se um zé da esquina quiser pegar seu contato e começar a te encher o saco, o mesmo vale pra linkedin, facebook, e etc na bio do perfil

Comment: Mas o perfil tem justamente essa finalidade, certo? Ali sim é o local para colocar os seus contatos, não na sua resposta.

Comment: Então estou entendendo que posso retirar esse tipo de informação em futuras revisões.

Comment: Já vi em uma postagem onde no comentário do código tinha o cpf e email do criador. O melhor é tirar mesmo 1) pq é ruido como uma assinatura. 2) Protege a informação confidencial do usuário contra trotes, spams e outras coisas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O melhor é editar a postagem e remover a informação sensível (email, telefone, cpf etc) pelos seguintes motivos:

- É ruido como uma assinatura e não contribui em nada no pior do casos pode ser propaganda ou spam.
- Protege o contato/informação contra mal uso sejam via trotes, cadastros de spam etc.

**Relacionadas:**

[O que fazer quando um usuário solicita contato via e-mail?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/733/91)

[Sugerir videoconferência por algum programa pra ajudar em dúvida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5697/91)

Comment: Quando falaram em trote só eu pensei nisso? https://github.com/haskellcamargo/gemidao-do-zap

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Comment: Trotes de antigamente: falsas promessas de emprego.

Trotes atuais: gemidão do zapezape

Comment: Trotes old school mesmo, receber ligações sem noção N vezes, ser cadastros em N serviços de vendas por telefone. Tem situação pior também haha

Answer (score 14):

Não se trata de um caso como o do tópico que foi mencionado algumas vezes sobre videoconferência. **O número de telefone pode ser de alguém que não tem nada a ver com o usuário que o postou, seja por erro de digitação, seja por malícia.**

Caso a pergunta seja popular o estrago será maior ainda. Imagine se todo dia você recebesse uma ligação em horário aleatório pedindo ajuda sobre algum tema de programação. É inviável bloquear o número de cada sociopata que ligar.

Proteja uma pessoa inocente. Edite de imediato. Em seguida **sinalize para a moderação remover o número de telefone do histórico de edição** pois mesmo após a edição o número ainda pode ser encontrado.